# Set numerous include paths?

Tags: php, include-path, set-include-path

I know how to set an include path:

```
set_include_path('/path');
```

But how can I set multiple include paths? 
For example: in two different directories.

Comment: The PHP manual page for the exact function you're using shows how to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Separate them with colons (:).

```
set_include_path("/some/dir:/other/dir:.");
```

More info on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Comment: Note this won't work on Windows. Use platform independent PATH_SEPARATOR instread of colons.

Answer (score 17):

To do this in a cross platform manner use the [PATH_SEPARATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant:

```
set_include_path('/my/path' . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/my/other/path');
```

FYI: You can also set the include path in `php.ini` or in your apache vhost configuration.

For your further reference: [PHP documentation on set_include_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

Answer (score 7):

### Setting Numerous Include Paths

Here is a way, in a **platform independent** manner, to set numerous include paths from an array of values:

```
$paths = array(
    'path/one/',
    'path/two/',
    'path/three/'
 );

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :-)

```
ini_set("include_path", ".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear;.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\Zend\library");
```